# VB.NET Why is my tab order being ignored, even when I have manually set each control's Tab Index in design view?

Tags: vb.net, tabindex

I have a WPF application.  My WinForms tabbing is acting crazy.  I went into the .designer.vb and set all controls .tabindex = 0.

I then go to the design view of a form and set the tab order as:

0.0.0.0.1

0.0.0.0.2

0.0.0.0.etc

[image: My forms Tab Orders]

.I have tried using the  button in VS.2008

I have tried manually setting the tab order on each control.

I have tried settings every control to 0 and then manually setting the tab order.

I have tried iterating the controls and setting the Z-Orders.

**What am I missing?!?**

Comment: Holy cow.  Biggest problem is that you can't even *see* the tab order.  Go easy on the panels.

Comment: All of your panels have the same tab order (0.0.0.1).  That's going to cause problems.  Since most of your panels only have one input control each, focus on ordering your *panels* first.

Comment: @RBarryYoung My panel order was set this way during one of my many attempts to overcome the tabbing issue.  Do you believe that setting my panel's Tab Order will result in my controls gaining their tab order correctly?  If so I will try this and Thanks!

Comment: @RBarryYoung An update, I reset the tab order on all forms and still the crazy tabbing persists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that..  I guess I'd start from here with 1) apply any and all possibly relevant Service Packs, and 2) check all of the add-ins and extensions to make sure that one of them is not playing havok with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be hard work with panels.  You have to treat each panel seperately, as RBarryYoung says.  Sort out the outmost panels and work inwards until you get to your controls

I find best way is to pin the Document Outline window (Ctrl+Alt+T) on one side of the screen to see how your you panels are arranged and the properties window to the other.

[Document Outline - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then set the order manually using the properties window.  I've never managed to get tab order to work as I would like except on very simple forms.

Comment: "I find best way is to pin the Document Outline window (Ctrl+Alt+T) on one side of the screen to see how your you panels are arranged and the properties window to the other." Great tip.